# Getting a 'diacritics' error not found in i18n-iso-countries?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, package, mean-stack, diacritics

I'm getting this error and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

**./node_modules/i18n-iso-countries/index.js:4:25-53 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'diacritics' in 'C:\Users\mandy\Downloads\shareitall\node_modules\i18n-iso-countries'**

I've tried googling but couldn't find anything. Also tried to delete the entire i18n-iso-countries folder in node_modules then reinstalling - but doesn't work. I've just had to reset my PC because it broke... Would be great if anyone could answer soon! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

installing diacritics
https://www.npmjs.com/package/diacritic
solved the issue